# PHP logical operators within IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I have the following code:

**PHP**

```
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}else
if($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9' && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9' && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}
```

Information is passed to the PHP page within the URL, such as:

```
?br=ABC&cr=MAY2014&pd=NOV2013&mn=TRUE
?br=XYZ&cr=MAY2014&pd=NOV2013&mn=TRUE
```

And handled as follows:

```
$brand = $_GET['br'];
$main = $_GET['mn'];
```

What is happening is that if `$brand = ABC and $main = TRUE` then the `analysis.php` is loaded successfully (which is correct).

However, if `$brand = XYZ and $main = TRUE` then `report.php` is loaded, which is not the behaviour I expect or need.

Is this connected with the way the operators work or is my code incorrect.  Any help and feedback welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`. Your current code does this:

```
if($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || ($brand == '1A9' && $main == '')){
```

This evaluates to true, because `$brand == 'XYZ'` is true. Use parentheses to correct the statement:

```
if(($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9') && $main == ''){
```

See [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should write conditions with proper brckets.

Try below code

```
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}else
if(($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9') && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if(($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9') && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}
```

Comment: ARGH!!!!!  Thank you for that, much appreciated.  Cannot believe I missed it. DOH!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}else
if(($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9') && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if(($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9') && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with operator precedence. Try this

```
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if($brand == 'ABC' && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}else
if(($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9') && $main == ''){
    include '../_inc/report.php';
}else
if(($brand == 'XYZ' || $brand == '123' || $brand == '1A9') && $main == 'TRUE'){
    include '../_inc/analysis.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be written in a much shorter way:

```
$include = false;
if($brand=='ABC'){
    if(empty($main))$include = 'report';
    else if($main)$include = 'analysis';
} else if(in_array($brand, array('XYZ', '123', '1A9'))){
    if(empty($main))$include = 'report';
    else if($main)$include = 'analysis';
}
if($include)include '../_inc/'.$include.'.php';
```